# PHPMailer Problems

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Okay, so I've downloaded [PHP Mailer's](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) class, required it using `require_once` then make a function for sending mail:

```
public function sendMail($to, $subject, $body) { 
            $mail = new phpmailer;

            $mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = 'USERNAME';
            $mail->Password = 'PASSWORD';
            $mail->Port = 465;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';
            $mail->From = "EMAIL";
            $mail->FromName = "FROM NAME";
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com;";  // specify main and backup server

            if(is_array($to)) {
                foreach($to as $x) {
                    $mail->AddAddress($x);
                }
            } else {
                $mail->AddAddress($to);
            }

            $mail->AddReplyTo("REPLY EMAIL", "REPLY NAME");
            $mail->WordWrap = 50;    // set word wrap

            $mail->IsHTML(true);    // set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $body;

            if(!$mail->Send()){
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And when I go to do (it's in the class $core)

```
if($core->sendMail('MYEMAIL@gmail.com', 'Something', 'Some body')) {
        echo 'Mail sent';
    } else {
        echo 'Fail';
    }
```

It returns fail. The code in the script holds the correct information, I've just used placeholders for posting it here.

Comment: Does not it says something like `Fatal error: Class 'phpmailer' not found on line #`?

Comment: @Shakti Nope, just says 'Fail', like the if statement tells it to

Comment: @Joshwaa: `sendMail` returns false if mail is not send (as you coded it) and what it returns if mail sent successfully?

Comment: @Shakti I've changed the function to `return $mail->Send();` so it should return true or false, depending on whether the mail is sent, and I'm still getting 'Fail'.

Comment: Are you sure the server URL and port number is correct?  Also, what do you get in $mail->ErrorInfo after the failure?  Should show any obvious SMTP comms issues...

Comment: @Shakti it's all included in one global file.
@Nick $mail->ErrorInfo returns nothing :s

Answer (score 3):

`$mail` contains the error message, do the following:

```
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    throw new Exception($mail->ErrorInfo);
}
```

instead of just returning "false".

Comment: Then please `var_dump($mail->ErrorInfo);`. What's the exact output?

Comment: Then try setting `$mail->SMTPDebug = true`. If that does not help, you need to really debug the phpmailer code, or use Wireshark to see what errors your SMTP session gives.

Comment: I've done that, and it's returned `SMTP -> FROM SERVER: SMTP -> FROM SERVER: SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected`

Comment: The remote server does not accept your SMTP connection, i.e. it wants a special authentication or SSL setup first. Contact your SMTP server provider for instructions.

Comment: I'm using xampp on localhost.. I take it it doesn't support SMPT?

Comment: You connect to Google's SMTP server, not localhost. So you need to look in the google docs for more information. It could also be that Google wants a EHLO (newer) and not a HELO (older). No idea if PHPMailer supports that SMTP version.

Comment: Any other mailing solutions you could recomment? @cweiske

Comment: I know PEAR's Mail class works with google, and the Zend Framework Mailer works with it, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
        if(!$mail->Send()){
            return false;
        }
```

should be

```
        if(!$mail->Send()){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
```

because functions by default return false, when the return value is not specified inside the function.

You can also go with the cleaner version:

```
        return $mail->Send();
```

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/
The other options seems good, but is your username and password set correctly? The ones that get sent to smtp.google.com.